# Convert drawn lines into bitmapdata - Bitmap.draw() + Sprite.graphics - wont work

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmapdata

EDIT: The convertation / copy process it self works, I just cant figure out how to tell the bitmapdata, which part of the stage to copy - I tried to solve that problem by movie the canvas to x=0 y=0 didnt show anychanges.
The only thing that showed a change was that I did move the canvas BEFORE drawing to zero, but this is totally buggy because the part of the drawing which has negativ coordinates wont be copied since the coordinate change only affect the bitmap if you do it before you start to paint

OLDER ENTRY:
I want to convert the Sprite.graphics into bitmapData, because I have a drawTool which allowes the user to paint lines, which are located inside the Sprite.grahpics I think.

I need to convert these lines to bitmapdata, because this allows me to deform them later on, but I cant use this

```
Bitmapdata.draw(Sprite.graphics);
```

And using only the Sprite instead of Sprite.graphics doesnt show any result =\
help is needed!

Comment: Can you more defined your problem ? Are you drawing something using Sprite object & you want to get its bitmap data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a matrix if you want to draw only a certain portion and from an origin other than (0,0). There's plenty in the Adobe docs on this, or a good example here:

http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000670.php

Comment: haha thanks a lot man =) Im quite new to as3 and dont know all the availible features! I think this should solve it

Comment: :) It took me a while to get my head around using matrices, but once you get them, they are really useful.

Comment: their really nice used them the a lot since I asked the question =D

Answer (score 0):

Only use `graphics` when drawing. The actual `Sprite` object contains what you want, so following your convention, simply do:

```
BitmapData.draw(Sprite);
```

Although for a literal example:

```
var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
// add lines etc using mySprite.graphics

var myBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mySprite.width, mySprite.height);
myBitmapData.draw(mySprite);
```

Comment: Good answer. You might add that if he wants to manipulate each line separately, he will need to draw each one on a separate sprite.

Comment: thanks man but I did already know that, it just didnt display as I wanted to

Answer (score 0):

I think, you've not completely understand usage `BitmapData.draw()`.

`BitmapData.draw()` is a All DisplayObject(Sprite, MovieClip, Shape, Text, Video...) drawing possible. because they are have a IBitmapDrawable.(more information refer a adobe document Is the best teacher.)

If you want implement Paint Board. refer a below code. very simple Paint Board. but some help you.

**try copy & paste.**

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var isDraw:Boolean = false;
var brush:Sprite =new Sprite();
brush.graphics.beginFill(0x0000ff);
brush.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,5);
brush.graphics.endFill();

var canvasData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(600,400, false);
var canvas:Bitmap = new Bitmap(canvasData);
addChild(canvas);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDrawStart);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onDrawStop);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, render);

function onDrawStart(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    isDraw = true;
}

function onDrawStop(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    isDraw = false;
}

function render(e:Event):void
{
    if(!isDraw) return;

    brush.x = mouseX;
    brush.y = mouseY;

    canvasData.draw(brush,brush.transform.matrix);
}
```

Comment: thanks man the "brush.transform.matrix" was the thing that I didnt knew =)